# Why is the length function not working in this for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, string-length

Why this code is not working after using length function ?

If I use  `for(n of names)` this for loop then its working fine!

I am trying to capitalize each first letter of the `names` array. So, firstly I split the names to get the each names. Then by using loop I wanted to reiterate each first letter of the names ,by using `toUpperCase()` I am making the first letter upper case and by using `slice(1)`, I am separating the rest part of names expect first letter.

```js
const namingConvention = function(name) {
  const names = name.split(' ');
  const nameProper = [];
  for (const n = 0; n <= names.length; n++) {
    const r = n[0].toUpperCase() + n.slice(1);
    nameProper.push(r);
  }
  console.log(nameProper.join(' '));
}


namingConvention('mk. john akm');
namingConvention('timari davis');
```

Comment: `const` is short for constant. You cannot manipulate the content of a `const int`. Use `let`

Comment: You also need to stop at n<length: `for (let n = 0; n < names.length; n++) { let name = names[n]; const r = name[0].toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);`

Comment: Shorter: `const namingConvention = name => name.split(' ').map(part => part[0].toUpperCase() + part.slice(1)).join(' ');`

Answer (score 1):

Few observations as per your code **:**

- As we are updating the value of `n` in each iteration of for loop, It should be defined as `let` instead of `const`.
- For loop condition should be `n < names.length` instead of `n <= names.length`.
- Logic to manipulate the names is not correct, Each name from `names` array should be access like this `names[n]` instead of `n[0]`.

Working Demo as per your code **:**

```js
const namingConvention = function(name) {
  const names = name.split(' ');
  const nameProper = [];
  for (let n = 0; n < names.length; n++) {
    const r = names[n].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + names[n].slice(1);
    nameProper.push(r);
  }
  console.log(nameProper.join(' '));
}


namingConvention('mk. john akm');
namingConvention('timari davis');
```

Workind Demo (More optimized/Compact solution) **:**

```js
const namingConvention = function(name) {
  const names = name.split(' ');
  const nameProper = names.map(n => n.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + n.slice(1))
  console.log(nameProper.join(' '));
}


namingConvention('mk. john akm');
namingConvention('timari davis');
```

Answer (score -1):

you are using n wich is a number as a array, the corrrect use would be to replace the n's with names[n] since the n is the index and the names are the array you are going througth

you alse need to change n and name Poper into nomal variables and not constants.

constants make the variable unchange able and the same the whole loop.
You can also get the first letter with charAt(0)

```js
const namingConvention = function(name){
    const names = name.split(' ');
    var nameProper = [];//var so it can be changed
    for(var n = 0; n<names.length;n++){//var n so the n can change
        const r = names[n].charAt(0).toUpperCase() +  names[n].slice(1);//names[n] is the string charAt gets the first letter
        nameProper.push(r);
    }
    console.log(nameProper.join(' '));


}


namingConvention('mk. john akm');
namingConvention('timari davis');
```